# Reading image(varBinary) from Sql Server Database using Native C++

Tags: c++, sql-server, database, odbc

How can i read varBinary(max) Image from sql server using native C++ code. Do you have any advice? What is the best way to do it? If possible could you please give an example?

**I tried to read image using COM(c#). It works perfect but i want to do using native c++ code. what is another way to do it.For example using ODBC or etc. I couldnt find any usefull article on internet.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are asking about C++ in the assumption this operation will be faster, that is unlikely to be the case.  In C# you would not use COM for this anyway ...

Comment: @AlexK. I want to learn what is another way to do it.For example using ODBC. I couldnt find any usefull article on internet.

Comment: Do you have to store it as binary in the database? This is usually always slow, if you want to store images, I recommend storing an image LINK instead, You can upload it to a repository, get the link and store that into the database instead.

Comment: @ManishMallavarapu I just want to read. Images already stored as varBinary.